# Number from Flask to Html is not shown correctly

Tags: python, html, flask

So i'm trying to send data (a number) from flask to html, but it's not displaying what i want it to display.

Python:

```
@app.route("/galery/1", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def project():
    if request.method == "POST":
        #rnum is defined 
        return render_template("1.html", rnum=rnum1)
    else:
        return render_template("1.html")
```

Html:

```
 {% for a in rnum %}
  
  h3 class="text-center">Answer = {{ a }}</h3

 {% endfor %}
```

Output:
[it has to show 960781](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNO9B.png)

Comment: Don't use a loop.  `rnum` is a string.  When you iterate over a string using `for`, it returns one character at a time.  Just delete the `for` and the `endfor`, and use `{{ rnum }}` in your substitution.

Comment: `{% for a in rnum %}` This loop indicates that you expect rnum to be a _sequence_ -- a list, or something similar.  In this case, rnum is a string, which is a _sequence_ of characters, so the code does what you asked and prints _each character_ in the string.

Comment: If you expect rnum to be a single value, why do you have that loop at all?